# Kotlin enums fail to cast after deserialize

Tags: serialization, kotlin

I've got a data class with a map in it. One of the values stored in the map is a Kotlin enum class.

```
public enum SecurityRole
{
    User,
    Admin
}
```

It serialized and deserialized correctly it seems, but when I try to pull it out of the map and cast it back to the proper type, it excepts with:

```
com.fff.security.SecurityRole cannot be cast to com.fff.security.SecurityRole
```

Looking at it in the debugger it looks totally fine, all the data is there, it just makes no sense! I've tried using Java serialization with it, FST's serialization, Klaxon JSON serialization, they all fail to deserialize this thing in a way that's castable afterward, what am i doing wrong!

Comment: Could you post code you use to serialize and deserialize object?

Comment: Looks like a problem with ClassLoaders. Do any of the deserialise frameworks allow you to specify one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when `SecurityRole` is loaded with two different `ClassLoader`s. Even if they are the same class, the `Class` object which was loaded is not the same *instance*. Most of the cases the solution is to instantiate the `ClassLoader` itself with having the other `ClassLoader` as parent.

Comment: Yes this was it! FST was getting a class loader via: ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader(); inside it's self. But it did allow you to override that, passing in a class loader gotten off my own class fixed it.